# jQuery animate function misbehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I am trying to create a side menu using jQuery in which the div `sideBarMinified` will be hidden and hover and will display the `sideBar`. On mouseout, `sideBar` will be hidden and `sideBarMinified` will be displayed.

Here's what I have :

HTML :

```
<div class="sideBarMinified">
    <div class="topClear">&nbsp;</div>
    <img src="images/miniLogo.png">
</div>
<div class="sideBar">
    <div class="topClearBig">&nbsp;</div>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
  <div class="menuClear"></div>
        <a href="#">Sample</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sideBar").hide();
    $.backstretch(["images/cover.jpg"],{fade:2000});
    $(".sideBarMinified").mouseover(function(){
        $(".sideBar").show();
        $(".sideBarMinified").animate({left: "-=60px"}, 0 );
        $(".sideBar").animate({left: "+=272px"}, 500 );
    });
    $(".sideBar").mouseout(function() {
        $(".sideBar").animate({left: "-=272px"}, 500 );
        $(".sideBarMinified").animate({left: "+=60px"}, 700 );
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
div.sideBarMinified {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(208,198,168,0.9);
    border-right:1px solid #333333;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;
    z-index:999;
}
div.sideBar {
    position:absolute;
    left:-272px;
    width:272px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(208,198,168,0.9);
    padding:0 2px 0 45px;
    z-index:500;
}
```

The issue is when I hover on the `<a>` tag, the div `sideBar` is hidden and the div `sideBarMinified` is moving to the left. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it intentional that div.sideBar and a.sideBar have the same class? Changing them to different classes will reduce confusion in your code.

Comment: @MattStone, actually I thought that the hovering issue for the `<a>` tag was that class issue. But prior to this, the `<a>` tag doesn't have any class. So in this case, the class of the `<a>` tag doesn't matter.

Comment: I put you code into jsFiddle and the hover doesn't seem to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/7fn86/1/  Are you sure this is all the needed code?

Comment: Hi @Justin. At least it is. Matt Stone 's fiddle is working.

Comment: @teami, backstretch is a plugin to create a fullscreen background out on any image i select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".sideBar").hide();
$.backstretch(["images/cover.jpg"], {
    fade: 2000
});
$(".sideBarMinified").mouseover(function() {
    $(".sideBar").show();
    $(".sideBarMinified").animate({
        left: "-=60px"
    }, 0);
    $(".sideBar").animate({
        left: "+=272px"
    }, 500);


});
$(".sideBar").mouseleave(function() {

    $(".sideBar").animate({
        left: "-=272px"
    }, 500);
    $(".sideBarMinified").animate({
        left: "+=60px"
    }, 700);
}); });​
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily do what I want but I got the error. My mistake is that I used the `mouseout` function instead of the `mouseleave`. Thanks dude! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was due to the hardcoded widths and negative margins used on .sidebar. The standard CSS box-model (`content-box`) ADDS padding to the width, resulting in a wider box than you're expecting.

```
div.sideBar {
    left: -319px;
    width: 272px; <!-- width is actually 319px when including padding -->
    padding: 0 2px 0 45px;
}​
```

I've updated your code in a Fiddle, check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Hm7zB/1/**

I'd recommend reading about `box-sizing: border-box;` which acts in a more logical manner by defining width to including padding: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the reply. Your code works great, however, when I start to mouseover the `<a>` tag, the `sideBar` hides itself. My intention is to make a menu out of this, so if a user mouseover the link, the box should not hide.